# How to create a texture from an EGLImage in desktop OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, egl

For OpenGL ES the [`OES_EGL_image` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image.txt) provides a function EGLImageTargetTexture2DOES to create a texture from an EGLImage. Is there an equivalent extension/function for desktop OpenGL (not ES)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think GL_OES_EGL_image should work with the Mesa drivers and desktop GL. glxinfo shows the extension as supported with both core and compatibility profiles. I did not see any checks for ES with a quick look at the implementation.

A grep through the Mesa provided GL headers shows no other occurrence of EGLImage, so GL_OES_EGL_image is probably your only choice with the Mesa drivers.

I am not sure though whether this behavior is specific to Mesa or other drivers also follow it.